# Mutex работает некорректно между процессами

Tags: c#, wpf, mutex

В `OnStartup`:

```
bool existed;
string guid = Marshal.GetTypeLibGuidForAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).ToString();
Mutex mutexObj = new Mutex(true, guid, out existed);
if(existed)
    ...
```

Код честно скопирован [отсюда](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/11.7.php).

Все должно работать, однако, самое интересное начаниется при попытке вывести Mutex в другой метод:

```
private static bool IsNotOpenAlready() {
        bool existed;
        string guid = Marshal.GetTypeLibGuidForAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).ToString();
        Mutex mutexObj = new Mutex(true, guid, out existed);
        return existed;
    }
```

Вызывается метод  в app.xaml:

```
if(IsNotOpenAlready())
    ...
```

Он всегда выдает true, вне зависимости, открыт второй экземпляр, нет. Однако, если оставить Mutex в OnStartup все работает. Почему?

Comment: Пробовали вместо `string guid = Marshal.GetTypeLibGuidForAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).ToString();;` написать `string guid = "vasya";`?

Comment: Конкретно "vasya" - нет, но они совпадают. Тут выяснились интересные подробности, сейчас обновлю вопрос.

Comment: ну, если просто поглядеть на ваш код, но почему бы, например, GC не прибить ваш мьютекс сразу после выхода из текущей функции. Ну и как бы вы ничего не захватывали вроде, так?

Comment: Объявил статическую переменную, в которую записал Mutex, и всё заработало. Видимо да, дело в GC. Если хотите - оформите как ответ. Но все-же интересно, почему в OnStartup GC не убирает ее?

Comment: в примере мы соаздем mutex вот так `static Mutex mutexObj = new Mutex();`. То есть как бы без имени. Почему бы не создать вот так `static Mutex mutexObj = new Mutex(true, "vasya");`?

Comment: а в примере, что вы привели, добавьте в конце проги, после `Console.ReadLine()` - `GC.KeepAlive(mutex);`

Comment: `Но все-же интересно, почему в OnStartup GC не убирает ее?` не понял вопроса

Comment: Итак, проблема уходит, если в методе IsNotOpenAlready сделать `mutexObj = new Mutex(true, guid, out existed);`, и в классе `public static Mutex mutexObj;`. Попытка использовать `GC.KeepAlive(mutex);` перед `return` из метода ни чего не меняет. `Но все-же интересно, почему в OnStartup GC не убирает ее?` Проблема решается 2мя путями, 1 - как описано в начале комментария, 2 - убрать метод и писать Mutex напрямую в OnStartup. Почему в методе он по стандарту убирается и не работает, а при прописывании того-же самого в `OnStartup` он не убирается и работает?

Comment: GC уничтожает объекты не сразу, а в тот момент, когда ему понравится. То есть, вот вы определили локальную переменную в функции - она может быть удалена из памяти через 10 милисекунд после того, как функия выполнится, или через 10 минут - никто не скажет заранее когда. А теперь наложите на это сверху тот факт, что имея переменную в мелкой функции без вложенных вызовов, оптимизатор может дать совет GC, мол, эта паременная не важная, грохни её. А если переменная в функции, которая вызывает другие функции, совет будет немного другой, и момент смерти переменной тоже. Но это мои предположения.

Comment: немножечко обновил ответ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы в, например, WPF приложении в `OnStartup` создаете просто локальную переменную мьютекса, то после того, как метод будет выполнен, переменная и сам мьютекс будут уничтожены сборщиком.

Чтобы такого не происходило, надо держать ссылку на мьютекс, например, в поле класса или в статическом поле.

UPD

Говоря об оптимизаторе и GC и почему в одном случае объект был уничтожен сразу, а в другом не сразу, вспоминается известный пример с таймером.

Возьмем от этот код

```
void Main()
{
    var timer = new Timer(Callback, null, 0, 5);    
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
}   

private static void Callback(object state)
{
    string.Format("Called at {0}", DateTime.Now).Dump();
    GC.Collect();
}
```

И запустим его без оптимизатора

[image: ...]

Мы видим много много вызвов таймера. А теперь просто включаем оптимизатор

[image: ...]

И видим, что вызвов таймера всего ничего. Почему? Потому что оптимизатор видит, что таймер не используется после `Thread.Sleep(3000)` и советует GC его удалить (как он это делает я не помню, если честно. Нверное удаляет из корней, по которым строится граф ссылок для GC). Но стоит как то использовать переменную после `Thread.Sleep(3000)`

[image: ...]

то всё снова становится хорошо. Отсюда можно понять, зачем нужен метод `GC.KeepAlive` и почему от [так реализован](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/gc.cs,313).