# События и сборка мусора в c#

Tags: c#, winforms, события, сборщик-мусора

Начал изучать концепцию событий в c#. У меня есть следующие классы:

```
class CustomTimer
    {
        public delegate void DateAndTimeHandler(DateTime dateTime);

        DateAndTimeHandler dateOrTimeUpdated;

        public event DateAndTimeHandler DateOrTimeUpdated
        {
            add { lock (this) dateOrTimeUpdated += value; }
            remove { lock (this) dateOrTimeUpdated -= value; }
        }

        public CustomTimer()
        {
            InitialStartedTime = DateTime.Now;
            int num = 0;

            TimerCallback tm = new TimerCallback(ProcessTime);

            System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(tm, num, 0, 1000);

        }

        private void ProcessTime(object obj)
        {
            dateOrTimeUpdated?.Invoke(DateTime.Now);
        }

    }

    class SuperCore
    {
        public CustomTimer timer = new CustomTimer();
    }
```

И небольшой пример работы с этими классами в WinForms:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public string StringTime
    {
        get { try { return label1.Text; } catch { return ""; }; }
        set { try { Invoke(new Action(() => { label1.Text = value; })); } catch { } }
    }

    SuperCore superCore = new SuperCore();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        superCore.timer.DateOrTimeUpdated += TimeUpdate;
    }

    void TimeUpdate(DateTime dt)
    {
        StringTime = dt.ToString();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

Я заметил, что при сборке мусора у меня перестает обновляться время на label1, т.е. происходит уничтожение события. Чтобы проверить это и убедиться, что так и есть, я при нажатии на button1 вызываю сборщик мусора. Гипотеза подтвердилась.

Это приложение является просто демонстрацией проблемы.

Вопрос:
**Как мне сделать так, чтобы подписка на событие сохранялась? Чтобы время обновлялось на label1?**

Comment: `timer` сделать _полем_ класса.

Comment: Не, `System.Threading.Timer timer` который сейчас внутри конструктора `CustomTimer`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо, заработало! А с чем связано такое решение проблемы? Я правильно понимаю, что такое использование событий безопасно относительно утечек памяти? Можете ответ оформить? Или я оформлю?

Comment: ну вы создаете таймер в какой то функции и после вы из этой функции выходите. То есть на созданный таймер больше нет нигде ссылок, а значит он мусор. GC его убивает, и он больше не обновляет ваши лейблы. Всё верно

Comment: Вот [похожий ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/990049/179763) с таймером, единственно что там я использовал `GC.KeepAlive(..)`, а вам надо просто таймер сделать полем класса.

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо, да, все логично, ссылок нет - объект - мусор. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо сделать timer полем класса CustomTimer. Код класса CustomTimer будет выглядеть так:

```
class CustomTimer
{
    public delegate void DateAndTimeHandler(DateTime dateTime);

    DateAndTimeHandler dateOrTimeUpdated;

    public event DateAndTimeHandler DateOrTimeUpdated
    {
        add { lock (this) dateOrTimeUpdated += value; }
        remove { lock (this) dateOrTimeUpdated -= value; }
    }
    System.Threading.Timer timer;

    public CustomTimer()
    {
        int num = 0;

        TimerCallback tm = new TimerCallback(ProcessTime);

        timer = new System.Threading.Timer(tm, num, 0, 1000);

    }

    private void ProcessTime(object obj)
    {
        dateOrTimeUpdated?.Invoke(DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

**За ответ в комментариях на вопрос спасибо Alexander Petrov и tym32167.**