# Таймер не работает C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, таймер

Делаю приложение на c# Windows. Использую в нем два локальных таймера, но после запуска они не работают(по крайней мере мне так кажется, ведь нет никаких признаков)

```
C#  
private void Fight_func(Event e)
    {
        //...
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer HeroAtkTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer
        {
            Enabled = true,
            Interval = (100000 / hero.SPD)
        };
        HeroAtkTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(HeroAtkTimer_Tick);

        System.Windows.Forms.Timer EnemyAtkTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer
        {
            Enabled = true,
            Interval = (100000 / e.Enemy.SPD)
        };
        EnemyAtkTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(EnemyAtkTimer_Tick);

        HeroAtkTimer.Start();
        EnemyAtkTimer.Start();

        //...

        HeroAtkTimer.Stop();
        EnemyAtkTimer.Stop();
        HeroAtkTimer.Dispose();
        EnemyAtkTimer.Dispose();

        //...
    }
```

Вот что должны выполнять таймера:

```
C#
private void HeroAtkTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hero.Attack(Form1.e);
        Console.BeginInvoke(new InvokeDelegate(() => Console.Text += "Some 
        Text"));//Просто проверка
    }
private void EnemyAtkTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1.e.Enemy.Attack();
        Console.BeginInvoke(new InvokeDelegate(() => Console.Text += "Some 
        Text"));//Просто проверка
    }
```

P.S. Console - текстовое поле.

Comment: Попробуйте вынести объявление таймеров в класс, подозреваю что по выходу из функции они уничтожаются сборщиком мусора.

Comment: Таймеры были объявлены в классе изначально(при этом проблема была), но я решил внести их в функцию, т. к.  они больше нигде не используются.

Comment: А зачем вы их в конце функции останавливаете и грохаете?

Comment: Поглядите привет с таймером [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/990049/179763)

Comment: @tym32167 Благодарю, это действительно помогло.